# tablesorter romanian alphabet parser

Tags: jquery, customization, tablesorter, alphabetical-sort

As I have almost zero knowledge of jquery and javascript, but I've been using tablesorter for one of my projects, and I kind of like it a lot, I need a custom parser that sorts one column by the Romanian alphabet, among various tables. Can someone help me with such a thing? The romanian alphabet which should be used in sorting is:

```
AaĂăÂâBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiÎîJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsȘșTtȚțUuVvWwXxYyZz
```

When I sort now, the Ăă, Ââ, Îî, Șș, Țț are placed at the end of the list for ASC order or at he begining for DESC ... 
I have found something like what I need presented here: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-custom-sort.html for the Icelandinc Alphabet ... should I just change the  Array.AlphanumericSortOrder to my alphabet and that would suffice? That code seems to be updated a long time ago for an older version of tablesorter ...

Comment: If will take a few seconds to try it and half an hour to read all the code.

Comment: @QuentinUK will do just that, meanwhile some advice or a more elegant solution from someone that actually understands jquerry code syntax (not just at a blind logic very entry level like me) and is acquainted with tablesorter could do no harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all you should need to do is swap out the sort order string. Also make sure to include the Sugar library.

```
$(function() {
  // define sugar.js Icelandic sort order
  Array.AlphanumericSortOrder = 'AaĂăÂâBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiÎîJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsȘșTtȚțUuVvWwXxYyZz';
  Array.AlphanumericSortIgnoreCase = true;
  // see https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar/issues/382#issuecomment-41526957
  Array.AlphanumericSortEquivalents = {};

  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme : 'blue',
    // table = table object; get config options from table.config
    // column is the column index (zero-based)
    ignoreCase : false,
    textSorter : {
      // alphanumeric sort from sugar (http://sugarjs.com/arrays#sorting)
      1 : Array.AlphanumericSort,
    }
  });
});
```